# Python Tkinter set widgets frame with grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is this.  I create a tkinter widget and later down the road I create a new frame that I want to add this widget to.  When I call .grid() on the widget the widget is placed on the first frame, not the newer one that I want it to be on.

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

By default a widget is managed by its parent. If you don't want that, use the parameter `in_` when calling `pack`, `place` or `grid`.

For example:

```
self.f1 = tk.Frame(...)
self.label = tk.Label(self.f1, ...)
self.label.pack(...)
...
self.f2 = tk.Frame(...)
self.label.pack(in_=self.f2, ...)
```

However, if you find yourself doing this a lot, you're probably doing something wrong. This is almost never necessary in most tkinter applications.

Comment: @ranger Can't you just do label=Label(frame1).grid()?

Comment: @JonahFleming: that creates a whole new label, rather than moving an existing label. Yes, you can do it if you actually want to create more widgets.

Comment: Ok. I get what he is asking now!